# Import multiple CSV files, select 1 Column from each file & rename the column with the file name in Jupyter Noteboos

Tags: python, csv, datetime, jupyter-notebook, python-import

Im trying to import 100 CSV files from this kaggle link - https://www.kaggle.com/natehenderson/nate-s-cryptocurrency-analysis/data

Each file contains the historical information for a different crypto currency.

Each file looks like this:

[How data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuinn.png)

for the current analysis I only need the Market Cap Column of each of the files along with the index which is a time stamp.

So for each file the only column needed is the Market Cap.
Then I need to append each column & replace the name of the column with the name of the file.

The final result should look like this :

[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLAVC.png)

Where each column contains the Market Cap & of coarse each value should correspond with the index, and the name of the column should be the same as the name of the csv file.

any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you started. This assumes you have a folder containing all the CSV files and that each CSV file has the same format, namely something like:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Market Cap
"Sep 22, 2017",1.23,1.25,1.14,1.24,513898,12916700
"Sep 23, 2017",1.28,1.35,1.18,1.23,1700200,13448400
```

As you are trying to write data horizontally, you will need to gather all the data into memory before it can be written. This script reads each file one at a time and assigns each row to a dictionary of dictionaries. The first holds the `date` and the second contains all the currencies that have an entry for that date. The `date` is converted into a `datetime` object to ensure that they can be correctly sorted when writing the output CSV file. As each file is read, its name is stored in a set so that a definitive list of currency names is available.

To output, the currency names are sorted and a `DictWriter` is used to save all the values. This has the benefit of storing empty values for any missing data:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import glob
import os

req_cols = itemgetter(0, 6)
all_data = defaultdict(dict)
currencies = set()
date_format1 = '%b %d, %Y'  # e.g. "Sep 22, 2017"
date_format2 = '%B %d, %Y'  # e.g. "June 22, 2017"

for csv_filename in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    with open(csv_filename, newline='') as f_input:
        currency_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv_filename))[0]
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        header = next(csv_input)
        currencies.add(currency_name)

        for row in csv_input:
            date, market_cap = req_cols(row)

            try:
                date = datetime.strptime(date, date_format1)
            except ValueError:      # Try "June 22, 2017"
                date = datetime.strptime(date, date_format2)

            all_data[date][currency_name] = market_cap

currencies = sorted(currencies)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    header = ['Date'] + currencies
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=header)
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for date, entries in sorted(all_data.items()):
        entries['Date'] = date.strftime(date_format1)
        csv_output.writerow(entries)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin -

So I ran the code with 2 modifications :

1) included the : import os library 
2) modified the date_format variable from : date_format = '%b %d,%Y'  # e.g. "Sep 22,2017" to : date_format = '%b %d, %Y'  # e.g. "Sep 22, 2017" , I added a space to match the csv type.

How ever when running the script im getting the following error : ValueError: time data 'June 4, 2017' does not match format '%b %d, %Y'

which is weird because the format is accurate. 

am I missing something here?

Comment: June might need %B to convert it. So you might want to add both with an exception handler to catch the first case.

Comment: ran the script with both exceptions, the output.csv fie does get generate how ever it's empty with only one field [output](https://giphy.com/gifs/csv-jupyterlab-26DNcmEtuGsqTvZEA/fullscreen)

Comment: Try copying the script again... I'd left `xxx` in the filename for my testing